# ASP.net : Refresh page with get parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, coffeescript

I have a problem when I try to refresh my page with a get parameter:
I initialize a hyper link with jQuery (I use coffeescript syntax)

```
id= $(this).data "id2"
url = window.location.pathname+'?Shop_id='+id
add2 = '<form><button><a href="'+url+'">Valider</a></button></form>'
```

My controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditProduct(string Shop_id){ ... }
```

each time, the url generated in href attribute is ok, the redirection is good when I try second and third time, but after I don't know why, the url doesn't contain the get parameter like:

`/Products/EditProduct?`

Instead of

`/Products/EditProduct?Shop_id=0844839`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line `id= $(this).data "id2"` is syntaxtically wrong. Lets assume if you correct it the id variable gets assigned to `"id2"`

Next,

```
var url = window.location.pathname+'?Shop_id='+id
```

will set url to `/Products/EditProduct?Shop_id=id2` this should very well hit your action `EditProduct`. To cross check this you could also put a `console.log(variableName)` after each line to check what value is being set in your add2 variable.

Mostly likely that your first line change will help you.

Comment: Sorry i use coffeescript for initialize my url. i do a console.log to check if the url generated is good, and it's always ok. The problem is not on the Jquery part. I don't know why but sometimes when i click on the hyperlink it works, and sometimes the redirection delete "Shop_id=..." from the url

Comment: there must be some way to find out what the url generated was. CoffeeScript or any script

Comment: I look directly in the html of the page, and with several console.log, the hyperlink's attribut href contain always the good url. I tried with window.location.href, same thing. when i click on the hyperlink it refresh the page without the get parameter. But the worst is that it works 3 times for 4.

Comment: of 4 times it works 3 times you say ! Super strange. Try this with a different browser.

Comment: same thing with different browser, the strange thing is the "?" in the url